# Clashes between count() methods - CrudRepository - Spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, repository

I prefer to warn you, my english is not perfect but I'll try to do my best.

I'm actually in an internship and my task is to create a webservice. Before this, I'm supposed to work with Maven and create repositories, models and others.

For now, I've got a problem with the repository of a simple Java class.

**Here is my class :**

```
package com.XXX;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

@Entity
//Generate getters and setters
@Data
//Generate a constructor with to arguments
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Day_ {
    @Id
    private int day_id_Date;
    private Timestamp day_Date;

    public Day_(int day_id_Date, Timestamp day_Date) {
        this.day_id_Date = day_id_Date;
        this.day_Date = day_Date;
    }
}
```

Pretty simple as I said.

**Now here comes my repository :**

```
package com.XXX;

import com.XXX.Day_;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface DayRepository extends CrudRepository<Day_, Long> {
}
```

I've actually took this from an example on internet. Works fine for him but not for me. I'm getting the following error :

```
    Error:(6, 8) java: types org.springframework.data.repository.Repository<com.atos.test.account.tables.Day_,java.lang.Long> and org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository<com.atos.test.account.tables.Day_,java.lang.Long> are incompatible; both define count(), but with unrelated return types
```

Now I've tried to override the `count()` method by doing :

```
package com.XXX;

import com.XXX.Day_;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface DayRepository extends CrudRepository<Day_, Long> {
    @Override
    long count();
}
```

But I get the following error (which is almost the same) :

```
    Error:(6, 8) java: types org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository<com.atos.test.account.tables.Day_,java.lang.Long> andorg.springframework.data.repository.Repository<com.atos.test.account.tables.Day_,java.lang.Long> are incompatible; both define count(), but with unrelated return types

    Error:(9, 10) java: count() in com.atos.test.account.repository.DayRepository clashes with count() in org.springframework.data.repository.Repository return type long is not compatible with java.lang.Long
```

I've looked into the `CrudRepository` class but the methods `count()` is the same than the one I tried. I've also looked into the `Repository` class because `CrudRepository` extends it but there is no method count.

**EDIT**

So I think I've resolved the problem :
Instead of extending my interface to `CrudRepository`I extended it to `Repository`. The thing is that I don't know if I can use the same methods ther is in CrudRepository, can I ?

Comment: You disclosed the package name in your error messages.

Comment: This is more a wild guess than certainty, but maybe it has to do with lombok. Lombok does some pretty heavy compile-time manipulation of classes. Since the given types in the error messages are identical, this might be the reason. Could you rewrite your POJO without lombok and check whether the problem still persists?

Comment: Indeed which is a mistake.
About rewriting, it's the week-end so I cannot have access to my computer but I'll try to do it monday. :)

Comment: Okay so I've tried to do it without lombok but I get the same error : 

`Error:(6, 8) java: types org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository<com.atos.test.account.tables.Day_,java.lang.Long> and org.springframework.data.repository.Repository<com.atos.test.account.tables.Day_,java.lang.Long> are incompatible; both define count(), but with unrelated return types
Error:(9, 10) java: count() in com.atos.test.account.repository.DayRepository clashes with count() in org.springframework.data.repository.Repository
  return type long is not compatible with java.lang.Long`

Answer (score 0):

You need to return type "Long".

```
@Override
Long count();
```

Comment: Actually I've tried it and it's the same.
I tried adding `java.lang.Long`, `Long` and `long`.
However it's more logical to write `Long` but the error is still here.